# Why Ubuntu 2204 hangs on first run?

Tags: boot, uefi

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 Completes, it reboots and before the ubuntu logo appears, the system stops. I tried to install in every way possible with no positive results.

I boot live session and start Gparted. The partition that corresponds to EFI presents this warning:  "Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for fat32 file system support:  dosfstools, mtools. ".   This is a BIOS machine, core i7, 8GB RAM, hdd 1TB, Gforce g600. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you selected the option to install drivers? The graphics need proprietary drivers.